# Checking whether a channel exists or has a duplicate - TypeError: fn.bind is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror

I'm trying to create a private channel in `Discord.js` v12. My code is below:

```js
const name = msg.author.tag;

        const everyoneRole = msg.guild.roles.everyone;

        if (msg.guild.channels.cache.find('name', name)) { //checks if there in an item in the channels collection that corresponds with the supplied parameters, returns a boolean
            msg.reply(`You already have a channel`).catch(console.error);
            return; //prevents the rest of the code from being executed
        }

        msg.guild.channels.create(msg.author.username, {type: 'category'})
            .then(parent =>
                Promise.all([

                    msg.guild.channels.create(name, {type: 'text', parent}).then(r => {
                        r.updateOverwrite(msg.author.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true });
                        r.updateOverwrite(everyoneRole, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
                    }),

                    msg.guild.channels.create(name, {type: 'voice', parent}).then(r => {
                        r.updateOverwrite(msg.author.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true });
                        r.updateOverwrite(everyoneRole, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
                    }),

                ])
            )

        const success = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Created, please see bottom of the server`)
        await msg.channel.send(success).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000})).catch(O_o => {});
```

I'm checking whether a channel exists or not. When I try to find a channel using the name the bot returns me as follows:

> ```
> An error occurred while running the command: TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
> You shouldn't ever receive an error like this.
> ```

I've looked at these posts:

[TypeError: fn.bind is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528836/typeerror-fn-bind-is-not-a-function)

[Way to check if a channel exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962679/way-to-check-if-a-channel-exists)

[discord.js v12 check if channel exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63083829/discord-js-v12-check-if-channel-exists)

[discord.js check if guild has a channel with a specific name, and if so, store that channels id to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192932/discord-js-check-if-guild-has-a-channel-with-a-specific-name-and-if-so-store-t)

But most of them didn't solve my issue.

I'm using `Discord.js` v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related to your usage of .find() method. With v12, the method has changed (View it [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#collection)).

You need to replace:

```js
msg.guild.channels.cache.find('name', name)
```

By:

```js
msg.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === name);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer. i will check this solution tonight and update this post, thankyou!